# how to join two datatable datas into one datatable to show in one gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

how to join two datatable datas into one datatable to show in one gridview

i.e in 1 datatable i have username and pwd and in another datatable i have that user details. how to show all these in one datatable to get those values display in gridview(asp.net)

any idea????

Comment: Do you have some additional Informations ? Are you using Datasets ? What Framework Version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge two datatable, here is the sample for that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
on=new SqlConnection("Data Source=MCN101; Initial Catalog=MergeTable; Uid=sa; pwd=");
da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table1", con);
da.Fill(ds1, "Record");
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table2", con);
da.Fill(ds2, "Record");
ds1.Merge(ds2);
GridAllRecord.DataSource = ds1;
GridAllRecord.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a join on the tables before reading them into a DataTable: [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: no not using join, wat i need is searching the datas with the cell in gridview. like that.(searching the datas using dynamic queries)

Comment: Just noticed that you were looking for the Merge method, which I suggested as a solution first, but then deleted it because I was uncertain what your problem was. You should give the lay-out of the two tables next time :)

Answer (score 0):

@Ranjana have a look at this [MSDN article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f122d7f4-3b7d-4d93-bd0f-8bb57cd990a4/) it deals with what you want..