# Asp.net Gridview asynchronous binding on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to bind asp.net grid view asynchronously.I have two method inside wcf service.Both method give data table as result.Currently i am calling this both methods synchronously.Means both Method1 and Method2 execute then result will display.But i want to bind this result asynchronously because it will take 10 to 15 seconds to execute both Methods.I want to bind such way that if method one is executed then result will display to the user inside asp.net grid view.whenever method 2 executed it result will be append.i want to do binding on server side not client side.so can u please give suggestion for that?

Comment: you can try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895061/how-to-join-two-datatable-datas-into-one-datatable-to-show-in-one-gridview-in-as