# Create a table using two database instances on ASP page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am very new to ASP and VB .NET

.aspx file :

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:e1ConnectionString %>" 
        ></asp:SqlDataSource>

     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:e1ConnectionString %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

code behind .vb file :

Datasource-1 from SQL server instance 1 :

```
Dim ElcidDwConnectionString As String = "dwstring"
        Dim strConnection1 As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(dwstring).ToString()
        Dim sqlConn1 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection1)
        sqlConn1.Open()
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT SR_number,t1,t2 
        FROM [dw1].[dbo].[StagedServiceRequest]", sqlConn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds)
```

Datasource from SQL server intance-2:

```
SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "select SR_NUMBER,address,start_date from [dw2].table2"
```

I need to join these two data sources on the column SR_NUMBER and Build a table with the data from these two tables on the aspx page. As they are on different server I am assuming the join is not possible with them.

I was using telerik Radgrid, it assumes only a single data source for building the table.But I want the data from data sources on two different instances.

Could some one suggest me a better way of doing this. Like I need to populate the table with the information from both these data sources with or without using telerik Radgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There 2 ways to solve this:

1. At your code fetch your data from the servers just as you are doing and merge the two datasets, see [how to join two datatable datas into one datatable to show in one gridview in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2895061/2202143). Basically is:

   DataSet1.Merge(DataSet2)
2. Use joins at one of your servers (inside an stp or view) and fetch from there, see [Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144051/2202143)

Then is just matter of setting the DataSource property of your GridView or RadGrid.

Comment: Merge will actually append the datasets right ? I wish to join my datasets on a key (i mean on a column value). Could you please let me know how can we do that ?

Comment: Say I have Dataset1 and Dataset2 , I want to join them on a field called SRnumber and fetch the additional data from both the tables.]

Comment: You're right, that will be a merge and not a join. I guess the clearest way will be option 2. But you can use **LINQ** too, i found this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Hope it helps...

Comment: Great job putting up more than one option.